# Facebook apprequest limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to send notifications to users of my facebook application with facebook apprequest api (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests). It's ok. Users get my notification. I have a question: Is something limits to apprequest sending? There is no in documentation. Maybe limit of user count in one notification sending or notification count to one user or somethin else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send multiple application request but one time you can send send more then 50 so, **I recommend you to **send 49 app request each time****

If you want to send more then 49 you can show again app request dialog and send again other 50 request .